# SSIS: Convert between Unicode and Non-Unicode Strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, visual-studio-2005

### Setup

I have a data flow task with:

- An OLE DB Source selecting all data from a database table (SQL Native)
- An OLE DB Destination of an Access 2003 File template (MS Jet 4.0)

So Essentially I am selecting a table and inserting it into a .mdb file.

### Problem

I have the error:

```
column [X] cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types
```

However If I add a 'Data Conversion Step' to convert all columns of type DT_STR to DT_WSTR, that error message goes away however I get the error message:

```
[DTS.Pipeline] Error: "component "OLE DB Source" (6289)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
```

Iv'e been Googling this problem for a while and still can't fix it.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the datatype of your source columns? Are those nvarchar?

Comment: All strings in the source (SQL database table) are varchars, not nvarchars.

Comment: Delete your OLE DB Source and add it again. It looks like its meta data is out of sync. I dont know why it would be tho

Comment: "selecting all data from a database" All data from a single table or is it truly that you have some query that is attempting to generate all the data from all the tables in the database? If it's the former, how are you acquiring the data? Did you select the table name in the dropdown list or write a specific query? What is  the source database? You list SQLNative but is that hitting SQL Server, SQL Server express, something else? What version is that database?

Comment: @TsSkTo - I have tried this multiple times including the entire Data Flow Task Object and the error reoccurs

Comment: @billinkc - The data is coming from a single table, The sql code is select * from tablename. It is connecting to a SQL Server Standard Database (Version 9)

Comment: SQL Server Standard Database (Version 9) is SQL Server 2005? I haven't seen it referred to as "9". What is the definition of `tablename` Are there any unusual column definitions in there? Double click the line coming out from the OLE DB Source and look at the metadata tab. What are the data types listed there? Is it just one colummn that is having the error or are they all failing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Select * from tblName
```

use

```
Select col1, col2, col3, etc from tblName
```

The reason I found is, when you use different database, they might have one or two column that cause issue as it's not mapped.  So when you use table query, be specific regarding column name.